# How can I solve these coupled differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

How do I solve the following system of ODE's?

$\qquad \frac{dx}{dt}=\{-(n+1)r_1+(m+1/2)r_2\}x+n\,r_1y$

$\qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=-\{(n\,r_1+(m+1/2)r_2\}y+(n+1)r_1x$

Comment: Please show the differential equation in source form, so we can copy-paste it into Mathematica and try to help you.

Comment: To the downvoters: Note that rabia is new contributor. You should allow new contributes some time to adjust to the spirit of the forum and fix their post. Please read the [Code of Conduct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/conduct) and try to be excellent to each other! I upvoted the question justy because too many downvoted it.

Comment: @user21 Good point. I took away mine so as to not discourage someone who has no reason to know the semi-obscure rules that we've all absorbed over time.

Comment: @b3m2a1, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As a new user you should check the documentation on `DSolve`

```
Eq1 = x'[t] == (-(n + 1)*r1 + (m + 1/2)*r2)*x[t] + n*r1*y[t]

Eq2 = y'[t] == -(n*r1 + (m + 1/2)*r2)*y[t] + (n + 1)*r1*x[t]

Sol = DSolve[{Eq1, Eq2}, {x[t], y[t]}, t] // FullSimplify
```

If you are looking for a particular solution then you need to provide boundary conditions?

If you are looking for a numerical solution then you need to provide numerical values to the different parameters as well as bcs and for this you need to use `NDSolve`?

Comment: thank you so much, its really help me.

Comment: @rabiarajpoot try it and feel free to ask

Comment: yes,I have already try this and get solution.thanku